# Setting global defaults for PHP's NumberFormatter attributes

Tags: php

I'm using PHP's `NumberFormatter` class to display some decimal numbers. I want to set some global defaults - global meaning it is set on every `NumberFormatter` instance created anywhere - for it's attributes so that I don't have to set them set them every time. (I know this can be achieved by reusing the same instance and injecting it into different classes, however due to some limitations I cannot do that).
Specifically, I want to set a global default for the `NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS` attribute. How do I do that?

Comment: @axiac of course it can't. It's the name of the attribute. The value should be changed.

Comment: You could derive your own class with the settings you want, then use this derived class instead of the standard `NumberFormatter`

Comment: The problem is, that it's actually being used in a 3rd party library so I can't do that either.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the class [`NumberFormatter`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) doesn't provide any method to set some global formatting attributes.

You can extend the class, implement static public properties to store the default attributes and in the constructor of the new class, after you call the constructor of the base class, set the needed attributes.

Something like this:

```
class CustomNumberFormatter extends NumberFormatter
{
    public static $maxFractionDigits = 12;    // Set the most used value as default
    // Other attributes here

    public function __construct($locale, $style, $pattern = NULL)
    {
        // Let the parent class constructor initialize the object
        parent::__construct($local, $style, $pattern);

        // Set default attributes
        $this->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, static::$maxFractionDigits);
        // Other attributes here
    }

    // It's good to redefine the static method create()
    public static function create($locale, $style, $pattern = NULL)
    {
        // Make sure it returns an object of type CustomNumberFormatter
        return new static($locale, $style, $pattern);
    }
}


// Usage
// Set the default attributes
CustomNumberFormatter::$maxFractionDigits = 5;
// Create objects
$formatter1 = new CustomNumberFormatter('ro-RO', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$formatter2 = CustomNumberFormatter::create('ro-RO', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
```

Please note that it works only for the objects created using `new CustomNumberFormatter()` or `CustomNumberFormatter::create()`.

The objects created using [`NumberFormatter::create()`](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.create.php) (aka [`numfmt_create()`](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.create.php)) are objects of type `NumberFormater` and they do not have any of the default values you set using the class `CustomNumberFormatter`.